# Is it possible to have an Autonomous Database hybrid partitioned table, with one of the partitions over data from DBMS_CLOUD.EXPORT_DATA?

Tags: oracle, partitioning, oracle-autonomous-db

Is it possible to have an ADB hybrid-partitioned table where one of the partitions is an external one over data exported as a dumpfile from the DBMS_CLOUD.EXPORT_DATA datapump format?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can create external or hybrid partitioned tables over data exported from DBMS_CLOUD.EXPORT_DATA. You can use the ‘type’ value ‘datapump’ as described in the [external table doc here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/query-external-data-pump-dump.html#GUID-9BF59C77-20FE-4971-9542-9F26927D89F5) when creating your hybrid table.

For example:

```
BEGIN
       DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE(
        table_name =>'CHANNELS_EXT',
        credential_name =>'DEF_CRED_NAME',
        file_uri_list =>'https://objectstorage.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/n/namespace-string/b/bucketname/o/exp01.dmp,
                         https://objectstorage.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/n/namespace-string/b/bucketname/o/exp02.dmp'
        format => json_object('type' value 'datapump', 'rejectlimit' value '1'),
        column_list => 'CHANNEL_ID NUMBER, CHANNEL_DESC VARCHAR2(20), CHANNEL_CLASS VARCHAR2(20)' );
    END;
    /
```

Note: You cannot create external or hybrid tables over data that is exported using the “expdp” datapump tool, which is exported in a different datapump format than that from DBMS_CLOUD.EXPORT_DATA.